# Manjaro won't load after moving .qcow2 file to ~/dir

Tags: boot, qemu, kvm, manjaro

I moved manjaro.qcow2 from `/var/lib/libvirt/images/` to the `~/VM/` and fixed XML `<source file="/home/user/VM/manjaro.qcow2"/>`

After this operations Manjaro says:

`error: file /boot/vmlinuz-5... not found`

I tried to create a new VM using 'Import existing disk image'. After that, I did `sudo chmod a+x ~/VM/` but it still doesnt works.

How to fix it? Maybe chroot for VM dir will fix it?

Comment: so, this is a majaro guest on an unspecified host? And you moved the file on the host from "root" (you mean / or /root?) to some unspecified "home" directory?

Comment: I moved manjaro.qcow2 from /var/lib/libvirt/images/ to the ~/VM/ and fixed XML <source file="/home/user/VM/manjaro.qcow2"/>. This is my host, I'm a root user.

Comment: I created a new VM with 'Import existing disk image'. After that, 
I did `sudo chmod a+x ~/VM/` but it still doesnt works.

Comment: Since you are dealing with two users in this question, the root user and some unspecified non-root user, it is essential to know what user is doing what (who runs the VM, for example) and what the permissions and ownerships are on the files and directories involved (the image file, its directory, the XML configuration file etc.)

Comment: You should definitely make clear where ~/VM/ points to.